# r- Velox extract error: "Error in boostFactory$makePointGrid ... std::bad_alloc"

Tags: r, extract, raster, velox

I'm trying to extract raster data from a grid of points (right now, n=8), but I keep getting am ambiguous error message, and I don't have any idea why. This seems like a fairly straightforward operation with Velox. It could be something wrong with my code, but I have followed the vignette pretty closely.

The nlcd raster I'm using is the [2010 North American Land Change Monitoring System (NALCMS) with a 30 m resolution](http://www.cec.org/tools-and-resources/map-files/land-cover-2010-landsat-30m).

```
#----Loading NLCD raster----
nlcd=raster(file_name)

#----Generating overall outline of selected states----
states.full = c("Maine", "New Hampshire", "Vermont", "Massachusetts",
                "Rhode Island", "Connecticut", "New York", "Pennsylvania",
                "New Jersey")
us = raster::getData('GADM', country = 'US', level = 1)

#----Generating regular grid within that outline----
st.contour <- us[us$NAME_1 %in% states.full,]
st.contour = spTransform(st.contour, CRS("+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=-74 +lat_0=40 +units=m"))
grid <- makegrid(st.contour, cellsize = 250000) # cellsize in map units! "(+units=)
grid <- SpatialPoints(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(st.contour)))
date() ; grid <- grid[st.contour, ] ; date()

#----Cropping the nlcd raster----
grid.r = spTransform(grid, crs(nlcd))
grid.r@bbox = matrix(c(1550000.0, 2550000.0, -434099.8, 722809.3), 2,2, byrow=T)
nlcd.crop = crop(nlcd, grid.r)
nlcd.vx <- velox(nlcd.crop)

#----Creating polygon buffers----
spol <- gBuffer(grid.r, width=500, byid=TRUE)
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spol, data.frame(id=1:length(spol)), FALSE)

#----Velox Extract----
date()
ex.mat <- nlcd.vx$extract(spdf)
ex.mat
date()
```

Comment: It seems that it is a memory allocation problem (https://github.com/hunzikp/velox/issues/34) and that you should split your raster & polygons in smaller parts that you process in parallel.